# ncurses: Is it possible to refresh a window without removing its borders?

Tags: c++, ncurses

Since I haven't found anything else online I'm guessing that wborder just "mvprintw"s characters to the appropriate parts of the window instead of actually making a border object or anything deeper. I would like to know if my understanding is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of it: usually one makes persistent borders by creating a window, drawing a border on *that*, and make a *subwindow* enclosed within the first window (not touching the borders) and draws on the subwindow.

The [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) include some programs which do this (some have screens which create a succession of nested subwindows, all with their own border).